# AngularJS - Unit Test with Windows Scrolling

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a directive that look like this:

```
angular.directive('myDirective', ['$window', function($window){
    return function (scope, element) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        var top = element.offset().top-w.scrollTop();

        function adjustTop(){
            var oldtop = scope.top;
            var scrolltop = w.scrollTop();
            var winHeight = w.height();
            console.log("scrolltop:"+scrolltop);
            console.log("winHeight :"+winHeight);
            var newtop = top - scrolltop;
            if(newtop>15){
                scope.top = top - scrolltop;
            }else{
                scope.top = 15;
            }
            if(oldtop!=newtop){
                scope.$apply();
            }
        }

        w.bind('scroll', function () {
            adjustTop();
        });

        adjustTop();
    };
}]);
```

I want to do an unit test to detect its adjustment on the element `top` position based on the window scrolling.

Here are my questions:

1. How can I mock to simulate the window scrolling in a unit test?
2. How can I have the web-page document to be longer than browser height to enable scrolling simulation?

**Update:**

After taking Andrew's advice, this is my `$window` mock:

```
var mock$window;
beforeEach(module('my-app', function ($provide) {
        mock$window = {
          scrollTop : 200,
          height: 960
        };
        $provide.value('$window', mock$window);
    })
);
```

When I run the test, I am able to get the result of `w.scrollTop()`, but `w.height()` returns the error

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'height' in undefined.

Without mocking, I don't get any JavaScript error in the test, but the `w.scrollTop()` value is `0` and the `w.height()` is the browser window height of the PhantomJS browser running the test.

So, How can I get a `w.height()` mock works in unit tests?

Here is the sample of code to better illustrate the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/w4h5q5hr/

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to provide a mock `$window` object.  You can provide a mock `$window` in a `beforeEach` clause. The idea here is that you are *unit* testing and you can just assume that `$window` works as designed.

Something like this will work:

```
var mock$window, scrollTop = 100;
beforeEach(module('my-app', function ($provide) {
            mock$window = {
              scrollTop : function() { return scrollTop; }
              bind : function(eventName, cb) { ... }
            };
            $provide.value('$window', mock$window);
        })
);
```

Then, in your tests, you can:

- spy on the window methods
- ensure that bind is called on the proper event
- ensure that `adjustTop` works appropriately with different scrollTop values.

This is sufficient for unit testing your code, but if you want to truly see that this code works in an actual application setting, you may want to try something like [protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but it seems to be doesn't work. When I tried to console log `w.scrollTop()`, it return `function () { return scrollTop; }`. Also, mock `$window` object seems to be doesn't work with `$window.height()` that I get the error: `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'height' in undefined` So, how to mock `$window` properly? Thank you.

Comment: You should mock those methods as well. include them in mock$window.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have updated my question to better explain the situation. Really hope you can help here. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Andrew, really hope you can give a hand here. I hardly find any reliable information about this on the web. FYI, I am using jquery with AngularJS. Would that be causing the trouble?

Comment: That's true, your best bet is to avoid using jquery at all. You can use the `window.scrollTop` and `window.innerHeight` instead of using the jquery variant of window.  Also, be sure to properly mock these properties in your test.

Answer (score 2):

Create spys for things you want to mock like:

`spyOn($window, 'scrollTop').and.returnValue(100);`

If you're mocking jQuery calls you can use $.fn like so:

`spyOn($.fn, 'scrollTop').and.returnValue(100);`